# Can I edit opentreetmap data using an API?

Tags: api, google-maps, openstreetmap

Is there a way to edit opentreetmap using an API, such as adding a new node to the map?

Answer (score 3):

There definitely is an API (in fact, every editing program uses the API to edit OSM).

The API is quite simple, REST-based, and its specification lives [on the OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API); currently, [API v0.6](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) is used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the OSM documentation?

Wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

Current API: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Stackoverflow-esk Help Forum: http://help.openstreetmap.org/